# Bypass Access Denied (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, access-denied

I'm trying to navigate a website with Selenium
I searched Google and said that adding user-agent would solve it, but it didn't solve it.
http://coupang.com/

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import time

options = Options()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument('lang=ko_KR')
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5")
options.add_argument("accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
options.add_argument("accept-charset=cp1254,ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3")
options.add_argument("accept-encoding=gzip,deflate,sdch")
options.add_argument("accept-language=tr,tr-TR,en-US,en;q=0.8")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('d:/temp/chromedriver.exe',options=options)

TEST_URL = 'https://login.coupang.com/login/login.pang?rtnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.coupang.com%2Fnp%2Fpost%2Flogin%3Fr%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.coupang.com%252F'


driver.get(TEST_URL)
time.sleep(5)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

elem_login = driver.find_element_by_id("login-email-input")
elem_login.clear()
elem_login.send_keys("id")
time.sleep(3)
elem_login = driver.find_element_by_id("login-password-input")
elem_login.clear()
elem_login.send_keys("pw")
time.sleep(3)
xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/form/div[5]/button"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

print(driver.page_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and add headers like so and tell me if it works.

```
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-charset": "cp1254,ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "accept-language": "tr,tr-TR,en-US,en;q=0.8",
```

Comment: options.add_argument("accept-charset=cp1254,ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3")

Comment: I added it as you said but it still hasn't been solved.

Comment: Let me re-assess it and submit the complete code here.

Comment: Are you using macbook or linux ?

Comment: ares : Code has been modified. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: justin : no i'm using Windows10

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36

Comment: I tried to change it to this, but it won't be solved.

Comment: @SnowMan I just tried the updated code and it works flawless. The only error that showed up with the mapping and setting of the chromedriver and setting up of the environment variables of the chomedriver in PATH.

Comment: @AresZephyr If it doesn't work well, is the site blocking it?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are able to navigate other websites using Selenium. I would like to understand if the Chrome Driver is set up properly. And to answer your question there is a chance that your IP is blocked, and in that case you can introduce proxy to navigate the site. But before heading there, validate that you are able to do with navigation on other sites.

Comment: @AresZephyr There is nothing wrong with other websites. However, if you press the login button, the corresponding side will be suspend.

Comment: Can you change the Xpath to '//button[@class='login__button login__button--submit _loginSubmitButton']'

Answer (score 0):

Not that crystal clear in which circumstances you are facing *Access Denied*. However I was able to access the webpage http://coupang.com/ as follows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('lang=ko_KR')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.coupang.com/')
print(driver.page_source)
```

Console Output:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<div id="browserSupportWrap">
    <div class="bs-wrap">
    <p class="bs-message">고객님의 브라우저에서는 쿠팡이 정상 동작하지 않습니다.<br />
        인터넷 익스플로러 업데이트, 크롬 또는 파이어폭스 브라우저를 설치하세요.</p>
    <ul class="bs-browser-download">
        <li class="ie"><a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/ko-kr/internet-explorer/download-ie" target="_blank">인터넷 익스플로러<br /> <em>업데이트하기</em></a></li>
        <li class="chrome"><a href="https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html" target="_blank">크롬<br /> <em>설치하기</em></a></li>
        <li class="firefox"><a href="https://www.mozilla.org/ko/firefox/new/" target="_blank">파이어폭스<br /> <em> 설치하기</em></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<![endif]-->




    <div id="container" class="renewal home srp-sync srp-sync-brand">
.
</script>


    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
        document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', '652323801535981');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');

</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=652323801535981&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="//asset2.coupangcdn.com/customjs/criteo/5.6.1/ld.min.js" async="true"></script>




<noscript><img src="https://www.coupang.com/akam/11/pixel_3401c526?a=dD1kMDI3YTFiY2NmYTZiMDg3ZDE3ZWRkNzc3MDI5ZDhhNzNiYzM4ZDkxJmpzPW9mZg==" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: -999px; top: -999px;" /></noscript>




<iframe height="0" width="0" title="Criteo DIS iframe" style="display: none;"></iframe></body></html>
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: coupang]

Comment: I'm sorry I explained it wrong. press the "Login" button on the top right. then the page won't load. Login button = 로그인

Comment: I can load up to that site, but if I try to go to the login page after that, I can't load it.

Comment: Main page -> login page